# Resolving dependency for $state.go in Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-services

I have a provider config which uses `$state.go` to jump to states. When I use `$state` as a function parameter it works, but when I try to modify the function parameters to support minification such as

```
.provider('Navigation',["$stateProvider","$state",function($stateProvider,$state)
```

then I get the following resolve dependency error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module apfPrototypeJs due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $state
```

How to circumvent this problem?

Comment: You can only inject `$stateProvider` in the provider wrapper where as you can inject `$state` service in the actual service, i.e in provider's `$get`. Example `.provider('Navigation',["$stateProvider",function($stateProvider){  this.$get = ["$state", function($state){       console.log($state)    }]}]);` But you rarely (atleast i never had to) inject a provider in another provider, unless you want to set up some kind of common configuration setup provider function.

Comment: @PSL you are a lifesaver! Indeed I was using $state in providers $get but I wasn't injecting the dependency there! Spent a whole day in debugging this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only inject `providers` in a provider because no services are instantiated at that point yet and also because the provider methods are used especially for configuration, they can only be accessed during the config phase of the app, it does not make sense to have the ability to inject any services. But You can inject any service (not provider) in the provider's constructor function defined via `$get` property.

i.e

```
.provider('Navigation',["$stateProvider",function($stateProvider) { //Inject provider here

   this.$get = ["$state", function($state){ //Inject $state here
       console.log($state) 
   }]
}]);
```

As an alternate syntax (using $inject to support minification) you could do:-

```
.provider('Navigation', function(){

    this.$get  = navigationService;

    navigationService.$inject = ['$state'];

    function navigationService($state) {
      console.log($state)
    }
}]);
```